# I have to check the convergence of the following series

Tags: calculus

I have to check the convergence of the following

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\ln^5 n}{n^2}, \quad \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\ln n + \cos n}{n^2}$$

and I need some clues regarding how to approach them.

For the first one, I tried using the integral test and eventually I got an answer, but I wanted to know if there was a simpler way that didn't involve integrating by parts 6 times.
For the second one, I tried looking for another series to try and apply the limit test, but I was unsuccessful.

Comment: Could you explain what you have tried so far?

Comment: They are both convergent. If you show your work, I'll show mine...

Comment: @abigmistake I see that in your previous questions you gave properly a context, why do you not try to do the same thing here?

Comment: You already have clues! The chapter in the book on infinite series has clues on more or less every page

Comment: I edited it, I hope it's better now.

Comment: Well done now it’s fine!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any $\alpha>0$ eventually

$$n^\alpha\ge \log n$$

then for the first one use that eventually

$$ \log^5n\le n^{\frac12}$$

and for the second one

$$ \log n+\cos n\le n^{\frac12}$$

then refer to direct comparison test.

Comment: Surely "For any $\alpha>$ eventually" would be much better? Not necessarily worded that way, just with the quantifiers in that order

Comment: Yes you are right, I fix that! Thanks

Comment: Got it, thanks a lot!

Comment: @abigmistake You are welcome! Bye